# How to show a tab bar controller along with sidebar menu after login in swift IOS9

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift2, ios9

I want to show a tab bar controller along with sidebar menu in homepage (Main Page). After a successful login if I call the delegate to main page with sidebar menu then tab bar does not load and if i call the tab bar controller after login then sidebar menu does not work, I am confused on how to call the sidebar menu delegate and tab bar controller together so it may show both together (Sidebar menu and tab bar together on main page) in swift ios9.

Here is my code in App Delegate that build my sidebar menu

```
func buildNavigationDrawer()
{
    // Navigate to Protected page
    let mainStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)

    // Create View Controllers
    let mainPage = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainPageViewController") as! MainPageViewController

    let leftSideMenu:LeftSideViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftSideViewController") as! LeftSideViewController

    let rightSideMenu:RightSideViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RightSideViewController") as! RightSideViewController

    let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:mainPage)
    let leftSideMenuNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:leftSideMenu)
    let rightSideMenuNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:rightSideMenu)


    drawerContainer  = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: mainPageNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideMenuNav, rightDrawerViewController: rightSideMenuNav)


    drawerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView
    drawerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView

    window?.rootViewController = drawerContainer


}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/05AQz.png

[Click Here to view Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05AQz.png)

Thank you.

Comment: image is attache at the URL:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/05AQz.png

Comment: Seriously newbies... include updates to your question by editing your question, not adding comments.